# Pasar función como parametro de función para ordenar lista encadenada

Tags: c++, c, lista, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Estoy haciendo un programa que permite la creación y manipulación de una lista encadenada. Ya he hecho los métodos para agregar, eliminar nodos, etc. Sin embargo, al hacer el método que ordena la lista, el profesor me ha pedido que lo haga con una función que recibe otra como parámetro. Sin embargo, esto parece no funcionar al hacer al llamado del método en el main. No parece ser la lógica de la función, sino más bien la forma en la que he implementado el prototípo del método en la estructura. He aquí el método mencionado:

```
...
int comparador(T valor1, T valor2){
    if(valor1>valor2){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(valor1<valor2){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

void ordenar(auto comparador(T,T)){
    if(this->tam <= 1){
        return;
    }
    for(Nodo<T>* i = this->cabeza ; i != NULL; i = i->siguiente){
        for(Nodo<T>* j = i->siguiente; j != NULL; j = j->siguiente){
            if(comparador(i->valor, j->valor)==1){
                T temporal = i->valor;
                i->valor = j->valor;
                j->valor = temporal;
            }
        }
    }

}
...
int main()
{
    Lista<string> mi_lista;
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("1 asd asd");
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("2");
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("10");
    mi_lista.agregar_nodo("-568");
    mi_lista.insertarEnPos(2,"lk");
    mi_lista.actualizarPos(2, "miau");
    mi_lista.imprimir_lista();
    cout<<"========================\nCon nodo eliminado:\n===================\n";
    mi_lista.eliminarElemento(4);
    mi_lista.imprimir_lista();
    cout<<"========================\nOrdenando:\n===================\n";
    mi_lista.ordenar(mi_lista.comparador);
    return 0;
}
```

Y este es el error que muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este sería el código completo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename  T>
struct Nodo{
T valor;
Nodo<T>* siguiente;
Nodo(T valor){
    this->valor = valor;
    this->siguiente = NULL;
}
};

template<typename T>
struct Lista{
Nodo<T>* cabeza;
Nodo<T>* cola;
int tam;
Lista(){
    this->cabeza = NULL;
    this->cola = NULL;
    this->tam = 0;
}

bool esta_vacia(){
    return this->cabeza == NULL && this->cola == NULL;
}

void agregar_nodo(T valor){
    Nodo<T>* nuevo_nodo = new Nodo<T>(valor);
    if(this->esta_vacia()){
        this->cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
        this->cola = nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        this->cola->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
        this->cola = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    this->tam= tam++;
}

void imprimir_lista(){
    cout << "Valores de la lista:" <<endl;
    for(Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza ; itr != NULL; itr = itr->siguiente){
        cout << itr->valor << endl;
    }
}
void insertarEnPos(int pos, T valor){
    Nodo<T>* nuevo_nodo = new Nodo<T>(valor);
    if(pos == 0){
        nuevo_nodo->siguiente = this->cabeza;
        this->cabeza = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    else if(pos == this->tam-1){
        this->cola->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
        this->cola = nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza;
        for(int cnt=0 ; cnt < pos-1; itr = itr->siguiente,cnt++){}
        nuevo_nodo->siguiente = itr->siguiente;
        itr->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    this->tam= tam++;
}

void actualizarPos(int pos, T nuevoValor){
    Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza;
    for(int cnt=0; cnt<pos; itr = itr->siguiente, cnt++){
        if(cnt==pos-1){
            itr->siguiente->valor=nuevoValor;
        }
    }
}

void eliminarElemento(int pos){
    Nodo<T>* itr = this->cabeza;
    for(int cnt=0; cnt<pos || (cnt==0&&pos==0); itr = itr->siguiente, cnt++){
        if(cnt==pos-1){
            itr->siguiente=itr->siguiente->siguiente;
        }
        if(cnt==0&&pos==0){
            this->cabeza=itr->siguiente;
        }
    }
}

int comparador(T valor1, T valor2){
    if(valor1>valor2){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(valor1<valor2){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

void ordenar(auto comparador(T,T)){
    if(this->tam <= 1){
        return;
    }
    for(Nodo<T>* i = this->cabeza ; i != NULL; i = i->siguiente){
        for(Nodo<T>* j = i->siguiente; j != NULL; j = j->siguiente){
            if(comparador(i->valor, j->valor)==1){
                T temporal = i->valor;
                i->valor = j->valor;
                j->valor = temporal;
            }
        }
    }

}
};
...main
```

Cabe aclarar que el profesor ha sido el que me ha indicado usar el tipo de dato "auto" en el parámetro de la función que ordena. He intentado con apuntadores, pero tampoco ha cambiado nada.
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

El error dice: no puedes usar `auto` como tipo de un parámetro hasta C++20.

¿Por qué no defines el tipo de retorno que esperas? En este caso, intuyo que debería ser `void ordenar(int comparador(T,T))`.

O agrega el parámetro `-std=c++20` al compilador para utilizar C++20. En CMake puedes cambiarlo con `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`.

Otro problema, C++ no acepta referencias a funciones de instancia. Lo que puedes sacar la función `comparador` fuera de la clase o hacerla estática.

Por cierto, [`function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) es más simple y se puede usar con [expresiones lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). En tu caso se  vería así:

```
#include <functional>

void ordenar(function<int(T, T)> comparador) { ... }
```

Comment: Hola, ya he cambiado la versión a C++ 20. También implementé la solución que dejaste en tu respuesta, sin embargo ahora me salta "function has not been declared"

Comment: @Juan agregaste le include?

Answer (score 0):

El auto como tipo de parámetro de función solo es válido en C++ antes del estándar **C++20**.
El auto es una deducción automática de tipo que es una característica de `C++20`, y si el compilador no admite C++20, tendrás que especificar explícitamente los tipos de los parámetros de la función, lo que creo que es un poco engorroso de hacer, pero sugiero que actualices al estándar C++20 y pases la flag -fconcepts a través de la línea de comandos en la compilación para habilitarlo.

```
g++ -std=c++20 -fconcepts teste.cpp  -o teste
```

.

```
teste.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
teste.cpp:126:31: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int Lista<T>::comparador(T, T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
  126 |     mi_lista.ordenar(mi_lista.comparador);
      |                      ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
teste.cpp:88:5: note: declared here
   88 | int comparador(T valor1, T valor2){
```

Este problema mostrado en el mensaje indica que el comparador es un miembro no *estático* de la clase Lista que solo será llamado en un objeto de la clase Lista.

**Corrección:**

```
static int comparador(T valor1, T valor2) {
```

He notado que estás utilizando el compilador [*clang*](https://clang.llvm.org/), y como propuesta para resolver el problema, he indicado la opción fconcepts y el uso de la característica de C++20, pero utilicé el compilador g++ a través de la línea de comandos especificando los detalles. Sugiero que utilices clang a través de la línea de comandos con las instrucciones que mencioné.

*Mirando la documentación de [**Clang**](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html), indica esa forma.*

```
clang++ -std=c++20  teste.cpp -o teste
```